# Disable USB storage access on non-admin account

Tags: security, windows-8.1, usb-storage

The admin processes should always run while letting other people use the PC using a non-admin account.

I want to restrict usb access for the non-admin account for preventive security. How can I do that?

Comment: This is something that is very easy to do using group policy objects. But I think it depends on what version of windows you have. Which version of Windows are you running?

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to restrict access to non-administrators do the following:

- Go to run
- Type in MMC
- Add snap in "group policy object"
- Click on browse, click on the users tab and choose the non-administrators group
- Click on finish
- Extend the policy and enable the "All removable storage classes: deny all access" option via the     following path:

  > User configuration --> Administrative Templates --> System --> Removable Storage access

Hope this helps.

Comment: How could this be done using a PowerShell script?