# Can I control extensions and contents of the files are passed via USB

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb

I mean can I configure USB ports of my laptop to pass via them only files of specific extensions (e.g. HTML, PHP, JS etc.) and automatically check their contents and if a file has allowed extension, but containts certain forbidden piece of text, block the file and not pass it to my PC. And if yes, how to?

I'm interested in a way which can be unlocked only with the rights of administrator.

ps. Windows 7 Home Premium

Comment: Offhand, its sounds like what you want is some sort of security scanner (program or script) since I don't believe this can merely be done via somehow restricting USB ports. And that scanner would likely be something you would need to write yourself (or pay someone to write for you).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a USB port configuration. You will need additional software that offers this feature. Especially since you want to check their contents for specific strings or similar. It's essentially a tool that would need to watch any kind of data write that happens and acts on the source of the that. Such tools probably do exist as a combination of a management software and security software that has some form of data leak/loss prevention, though those tools usually try to avoid exfiltration not infiltration.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for such software, but without success. Or maybe edit(s) of some policy, the registry etc.

Comment: If you're just looking for a software check out the Software Recommendation exchange as that's off-topic. You won't be able to get what you want by just editing the registry or setting up a policy. Unless you want to restrict [access to mass storage](https://superuser.com/questions/689977/disable-usb-storage-access-on-non-admin-account) altogether.